# Can we connect an external ADC with PIC16F877A? Or it's compulsory to use the internal ADC of the PIC?

Tags: pic, adc

I am making project measuring pollution. I want to display carbon particles in parts per million on an LCD by using mq7 sensor. Can I use an external ADC (ADC0808)? Or do I have to use the internal ADC?

Comment: Of course you CAN use external ADCs... you just need to get the data into the PIC

Answer (score 3):

You can interface a pic microcontroller with just about any available sensor given that the pic you use and the ADC that you interface with share a data protocol.  So if you use a PIC with an SPI peripheral, you can interface with ADCs which use SPI to communicate.  Other protocols which many pics support include: I<sup>2</sup>C, UART, CANbus, IRDA, and USB.  Through software, it also supports the Maxim "one-wire interface," as well as possibly many others (I can't think of any more off the top of my head).  With just lots of pins, you can also support a multitude of parallel interface protocols out in the wild.

Realistically, I would expect that you would need the I<sup>2</sup>C, SPI, or UART to interface with something like 90% of the ADCs out there.

The ADC inside the PIC doesn't hold any special power over whether or not you can use an external ADC. There's no interface/IC "DRM" or something like that.

Hope that helps.

---

EDIT: So I'm not sure which exact chip you're planning on using (on digikey there's both a TI and NXP component with "ADC0808" in the part name), but it looks like this is an **extremely** high sampling rate for an ADC designed for similarly high-speed applications.  In the NXP document it suggests:

- 2.5G and 3G cellular base infrastructure radio transceivers
- Wireless access systems
- Fixed telecommunications

For a project which is just sampling ppm of pollution (a value which shouldn't vary terribly frequently), this seems like beyond overkill. The PIC16F877A is only designed to run at up to 20MHz, and since the ADC you've selected samples at up to 250MHz, the PIC won't even be able to process the data coming out of the ADC.

The NXP version appears to use a SPI-like protocol or parallel output, and the TI uses parallel only. Both of these are, in theory, able to interface with a pic16f887a.

In answer to your question: yes, the pic *can* talk to the ADC0808, it should not. They are not designed to tackle problems together.

Comment: so there's no problem in using external ADC0808..?.if both pic and adc has same interface??..or else diretly we can connet the sensor with pic?

Comment: @AAKASH : I saw which pic you were planning on using in the title when I re-read your question.  I modified my answer to feature more information about what you're doing.  You are able to interface these two chips, but the PIC will not be able to usefully utilize the information coming out of the ADC.  Imagine that the ADC is like a firehose of information, and the PIC16F877A is like a teacup with a straw in it.  If you aim the hose at the teacup, it'll fill with water, but you won't be getting as much out of the straw as you're putting in with the hose.

Comment: SPI, at least, is quite easy to interface without using a dedicated peripheral.  So not even an SPI perihperal is necessary, just a few GPIO lines.